# After upgrading my application from wildfly-25 to wildfly-28 Busy Task Thread Count increasing and not releasing

Tags: wildfly-28

My application working fine in wildfly-25 but after upgrading in wildfly-28, Busy Task Thread Count increasing and not decreasing due to which it is getting full and application stop responding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjxNW.png)

Comment: There's not really enough details to go on here. A more detailed thread stack trace would be needed at a minimum. Also migrating from 25 to 28 would have required a migration to Jakarta EE 10.